# How can i convert a Shared Project in to a PCL project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm working on a mobile-app project using Xamarin Forms i create it to be a Shared Project, but now i need a PCL to insert something like Maps or SQLite, how can i convert it without lose all my work? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new PCL Project in the same Folder as your old shared Project and than just add all files to the new project. (e.g.: Via Drag and Drop from Windows Explorer to Visual Studio)

Comment: This is not a workable solution on Mac because the Mac doesn't import the linking between Xaml files and the code-behind .cs files. This means I'd have to recreate all those files by hand by making new files of the same name and then copy-pasting the contents of the original files. With a large amount of files this gets ridiculous.